# Can you use contacted forms like " 've " without joining them to a noun/pronoun?

Tags: contractions

Is a sentence like this fine, maybe in spoken English:

"I love these films and books, **'ve** seen and read them multiple times".

Do you have to add a noun, or at least use the full form "have"?

Answer (score 1):

In speech you may say something that sounds like

> I love these films and've seen them many times.

But we don't write that, either we omit the parallel "I"

> ... films and have seen them ...

or include I

> ... films, and I've seen them...